# Help with output file formating and stylying using ascii art?

Tags: c#, ascii, text-files, ascii-art

I am creating a C# program that is outputting a basic .txt file with a lot of information. I am using formatting to align the information so that it is easier to read, so that is not an issue.

I want to make the output file look nice/fancy so that it is easier to read and each to find sections of data. The text file is a basic notepad file so I cannot use bold or italic to help separate out headers and specif areas of data.

I have tried using the following ascii chars *, -, _ to create line breaks to separate information and it helps make the file look better. I was curious if anyone else has any other useful ways to make the output file look nicer and easier to read. I have tried searching and haven't had much luck. I am sure that some of you have found ways to make an output file look better.

Thanks!

Some examples below:

"****************************"

Header Info

"*****************************"

"--------------------"

Infomation Here

"--------------------"

Comment: are you asking about code or simply a format?

Comment: I am asking for ideas, be code or a format. I was curious if anyone had any ideas on how to make a basic text file with a lot of data look better and easier to navigate. By using different ASCII characters, or other things? I tried to provided an example using *, and -.

Comment: What do you mean you can use bold and italic? Notepad and .txt only support plain text.

Comment: @Brian I forgot the not, it was suppose to be cannot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like Shibumi's answer but in case you wanted more examples, go in to the faqs here [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/)

Just go pick a game (top games or whatever) and look in the FAQ section. All FAQs at that website are txt files and you might get some good examples of things you can do there.

Comment: Great Idea, looking at the game faqs have a lot of different styles. I wasn't have much luck finding anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

I've always been a fan of the Em Dash character for lines, if that's all I need. (ALT+0151)

```
—————————————————————————————————————————
```

Produces a nice, solid line.

If you're really going to go all out, there are the old border characters.

```
╔═════════════════╗
║ AMAZING  OUTPUT ║
╟─────────────────╢
║ 1) Dog          ║
║ 2) Elephant     ║
║ 3) Condor       ║
║ 4) Liger        ║
╟─────────────────╢
║▒▓▒▓▒▓▒▓▒▓▒▓▒▓▒▓▒║
╚═════════════════╝
```

You can find all of those (in Windows, at least) in charmap.exe. Scroll to the bottom.